# Where to specify an app version on a Laravel app?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I used to specify the app version inside `composer.json` until I read somewhere here in Stack Overflow that it was a bad practice. What is the standard file to specifying the app version on a PHP Laravel application? (i.e: in **.NET** that'd be the *config file*, on **iOS** it'd be the *info.plist*, on **Android** it'd be the *Manifest*, etc...)

Comment: Do you mean dev version and live version? if thats the case you should specify it in the .env file in the root of your project.

Comment: I'm talking about the release version, release `1.0.1`, `1.2.0`,  `1.5.3-RC2`, etc

Comment: I think, you are looking for Git tagging. http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging

Comment: I've been using tags so far, but I thought there was some kind of file like on Android/iOS/.Net source codes, but I haven't found anything like that related to web apps, so I guess people only uses git tags?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`config/app.php` is definitely the place for such information.

Why ? Because the configuration files are (or should be) included in your versioning flow and they (should) contain non-sensitive information about your application. The perfect place for a simple version indicator.

under the `name` index of the array, you could set a `version` index like this

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Version
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This value is the version of your application. This value is used when
| the framework needs to place the application's version in a notification
| or any other location as required by the application or its packages.
*/

'version' => '1.0.0',
```

Comment: This actually didn't work for me - I added this to my app.php within the return section, but config('app.version') returns blank. If I figure it out I'll add my answer.  Laravel 5.4.

Comment: My issue was a configuration cache. `php artisan config:clear` fixed things right up.

Answer (score 11):

@delatbabel

has a great start for version

config/app.php

```
'version' => env('APP_VERSION', '1.0.0'),
```

for config/bugsnag:

```
'app_version' => env('APP_VERSION', '1.0.0'),
```

then you can simply get your version with:

```
config('app.version')
```

### Docker

now in docker you could set a default version on build:

```
ENV APP_VERSION=1.0.0
```

for example with circle CI you can add your build number:

```
ARG BUILD_NR
ENV APP_VERSION=1.0.$BUILD_NR
```

Now in your config.yml, you can add  following job commando:

```
 deliver-prod:
    machine: true
    steps:
      - checkout
      - docker build --build-arg BUILD_NR=$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM .
```

Comment: From container point of view. App versioning in ENV makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: than vs then. Check it up

Answer (score 4):

I normally set it in my .env file and then pick that up in a config.

e.g. .env says:

```
APP_VERSION=2.1
```

config/app.php says:

```
'version' => env('APP_VERSION', '0.0.1-alpha'),
```

Comment: I don't think that's a good choice since .env should be not versioned.

Comment: Where would you put it then? I'm still wondering why composer hasn't a place work this like package.json does.

Answer (score 1):

My approch for now: GitLab pipeline writes the "version.php" file after every successful build. The file has the following content:

```
<?php const VERSION = '1.2.3';
```

In the "config/app.php" I include the file

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../version.php';

...

'version' => VERSION,

...
```

The version can be queried as follows (e.g. as a route):

```
Route::get('api/version', function () {
   return ["version" => config('app.version')];
})
->name('version');
```